# How to create actors transparently across an Akka cluster

Tags: scala, akka, cluster-computing, actor

I have an actor system shown in the following graph.

```html
Master
|
|--Monitor
|
|--Supervisor
      |
      |--Device #1
      |--Device #2
      |-- ...
      |--Device #N
```

The Master actor starts the Monitor actor and the Supervisor actor.

The Monitor actor fires a message telling itself to check the device inventory every 30 seconds. For each device that exists in the inventory, it sends a message to the Supervisor actor to register the device.

The Supervisor actor starts the device actor when it receives the message from the Monitor actor to register the device.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/aries-zhang/akka-demo) on github.

Everything works pretty well in a single JVM instance, but when it comes to cluster mode, I start to be confused.

As I expected, with the following configuration, the previous actor tree should run transparently in the cluster machines. All the actors should be created across the cluster, and I should not care on which machine the actors are created.

On instance #1:

```html
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2551
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://example@127.0.0.1:2551",
    ]
  }
}
```

On instance #2:

```html
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "cluster"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2552
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://example@127.0.0.1:2551",
    ]
  }
}
```

What I expected:

```html
Master (On node 1)
|
|--Monitor (On node 2)
|
|--Supervisor (On node 2)
      |
      |--Device #1 (On node 1)
      |--Device #2 (On node 1)
      |-- ...
      |--Device #N (On node 2)
```

But, it ends up running two identical actor trees in the cluster: each node runs one actor tree separately as the following graph shows:

```html
Node 1             |   Node2
                   | 
Master             |   Master
|                  |   |
|--Monitor         |   |--Monitor  
|                  |   | 
|--Supervisor      |   |--Supervisor 
    |              |       |      
    |--Device #1   |       |--Device #1
    |--Device #2   |       |--Device #2
    |-- ...        |       |-- ... 
    |--Device #N   |       |--Device #N
```

I also tried to run the Master actor as a singleton actor in the cluster, but it ends up running a single actor tree on the very node on which the Master is started.

So, my question is, how could I create an actor across the cluster by calling `context.actorOf(DeviceActor.props(deviceId))`, without carefully designing the actor tree with cluster singleton and cluster sharding?

Comment: [akka-cluster-sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.5/scala/cluster-sharding.html) is probably what you need here.

Comment: Thanks @Horusiath. I misapprehended what Akka cluster sharding does in the beginning and though quite laconic, your reply helped point me the right direction :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is the exact definition of [Akka cluster sharding](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/cluster-sharding.html?language=scala).

> Cluster sharding is useful when you need to distribute actors across several nodes in the cluster and want to be able to interact with them using their logical identifier, but without having to care about their physical location in the cluster, which might also change over time.

It's pretty simple to set it up, especially if you already have a cluster. Monitor would be a Cluster Singleton so that there's only one alive on the cluster, and each Device would be an *entity* identified by the device ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ghostdogpr , now I completely understand how cluster sharding works. I was expecting Akka cluster to have everything done, but it seems not possible at the moment. I modified my code according to your suggestion and now it works well with all the machines in the cluster. The code can be seen here: https://github.com/aries-zhang/akka-demo/tree/cluster-sharding for those who would like to read as a reference.

Comment: Another good material for Akka-beginners who might be confused like me: http://michalplachta.com/2016/01/23/scalability-using-sharding-from-akka-cluster/ .